# Use AspectJ aspects in Spring project

Tags: spring, aspectj

I am working on a large Spring Boot application and want to introduce an apsect. As I need "if()" pointcut designators, I need more than Spring AOP. But: 
- I don't explicitly define my Aspect as a Spring Aspect, yet it seems to be handled by Spring 
-If I define an aspect in a ".js" file, it is not found by the weaver.

I followed the instruction in https://www.baeldung.com/aspectj very closely. Basically I use a runtime weaver plugin for my maven project and register the aspect in an "aop.xml" file.

How can I separate the life cylce of my aspect from Spring?

```java
package myApp;

public aspect MyAspect {

    pointcut prepInFile() :
            execution(public void MySpringBootApp.execute());

    after(): MyMethod() {
        System.out.println("*** I am here ***");
    }

}
```

```xml
<aspectj>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="myApp.MyAspect"/>
        <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">
            <include within="myApp"/>
        </weaver>
    </aspects>
 </aspectj>
```

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}"/org/aspectj/
                    aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/
                    aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                </argLine>
                <useSystemClassLoader>true</useSystemClassLoader>
                <forkMode>always</forkMode>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: It seems like EnableAspectJAutoproxy finds all @Aspect annotated classes. But I don't see how I can deactivate it...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, AspectJ source files are not JavaScript, i.e. they don't have a `*.js` file extension, rather `*.aj`.

Then, instead of `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` (which activates proxy-based Spring AOP) you need to to what is describes in the [Spring manual section of AspectJ](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj), e.g. use `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` as described in the [section about load-time weaving](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-aj-ltw).

Please also note that native syntax AspectJ files need to be compiled by the AspectJ compiler. For that you want to use the [AspectJ Maven plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/).